# Running a python script from shell_exec in PHP does not import MySQLdb

Tags: php, python

I am trying to use php to execute a python script that uses MySQLdb. When I run the python script in the terminal, it works fine. When I run the python script using shell_exec in PHP, it only works when import MySQLdb is removed. It seems like python is not importing MySQLdb only when shell_exec is used to run the script. How can I import MySQLdb through shell_exec?

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("/anaconda3/bin/python3.6 /Users/user/application/test.py");
echo $output;
?>
```

Here is the python code:

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
print("hello world")
```

Comment: How did you run in terminal?

Comment: I think you got an error because of that the path is not valid, did you check it with the full path?

Comment: Which path is not valid? When I run the command /anaconda3/bin/python3.6 /Users/user/application/test.py in the terminal, I get the output I want. It only does not work when I run the php script.